# Rotating a UIView with alpha = 0

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, alpha, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIView that I rotate with this code:

```
helpView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians( rotationAngle ));
```

Where degreeToRadians just is a macro to convert from degrees to radians.

This works fine as long as the view is visible, eg alpha = 1. When I hide it (alpha = 0, which I animate) it does not rotate any more. I guess this is a smart way for the devices to "save" on drawing time, but is there any way I can force it to be drawn even when alpha is 0? Otherwise I will have to rotate it before I show it again.

Any good ideas?

Thanks

Edit: This is the code I use to show/hide the view.

```
-(void)showHelp
{
    bool helpAlpha = !helpView.alpha;
    CGFloat newScale;

    if (helpView.alpha) {
        newScale = kHelpSmall;
        helpView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(kHelpBig, kHelpBig);
    } else {
        newScale = kHelpBig;
        helpView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(kHelpSmall, kHelpSmall);
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:(kAnimationTimeShort / 2) animations:^(void) {
        [helpView setAlpha:helpAlpha];
        helpView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newScale, newScale);
    }];
}
```

As you see I also scale it for a nicer effect. Works perfect when visible, does not rotate when alpha = 0. Rotation is done in another method, where I would prefer to keep it as I also rotate some other views there.

Comment: Hm... and how can you detect that your view is not drawn when it's alpha is 0? Can you post a piece of code where you make helpView visible.

Comment: Hi Zapko, please see my edit. Once I show it I can see that it has not been rotated while hidden.

Comment: I believe Deepak is right about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the transform every time you use `CGAffineTransformMake*`. If you do this, you will get either a rotated transform or a scaled one. I am assuming the scaled one is after the rotated one and hence you aren't able to see the view rotated. If you need both the effects to remain, you will have to use [`CGAffineTransformRotate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000946-CH1g-F16984). So a scale and rotate will be

```
helpView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(kHelpSmall, kHelpSmall);
helpView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(helpView.transform, degreesToRadians(rotationAngle));
```

The order might vary.

Comment: Hi Deepak. It sounds reasonable, but then why does it work when it is visible? Same code running, only difference is the alpha value...

Comment: What are the values of `kHelpSmall` and `kHelpBig`?

Comment: kHelpSmall is 0.1f and kHelpBig is 1.0f, give's it a zooming effect

Comment: The view is at its original size when it is visible. So a rotation will not have an effect on the the scale. Change it to 1.2f or something and I am guessing you will notice a difference. This is not the case when the view is invisible and it is scaled to 10% of its original size.

Comment: Hi Deepak. You were right. I changed the scaling factors and made the view visible at all time and it is indeed reset with every CGAffineTransform. Thanks for a fast answer with a good explanation :-) And I learned something new today.